# Setting a delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I believe this is pretty basic, but i haven't been able to find anything about it.

I have a viewController witch has a modal segue to a navigationController with a bunch of form sheet viewControllers. Like this:

viewController A ---(modal segue)---> navigationController ---> viewController B ---> viewController C

In viewController C I have made a delegate, like this:

```
@protocol ViewControllerCDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myMehtod;
@end

@interface ViewControllerC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewControllerCDelegate> myDelegate;
```

(and I've synthesized myDelegate)

I want to set myDelegate to be viewController A. My question is, where and how do I do that?

I've tried to to this in the viewDidLoad of viewController A:

```
ViewControllerC *delegateController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerC"];
delegateController.myDelegate = self;
```

but the delegate does not appear to get set. Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `delegateController` is actually being instantiated?  Are you holding onto that reference somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of ViewControllerC that you reference in the above code segment is the one that actually gets used eventually??  Ie, you're not instantiating the same view controller elsewhere?

Comment: You should also set the delegate when ViewControllerC is presented, not when ViewControllerA is presented.  And you shouldn't need to synthesize myDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do instantiateViewController, you're creating a *NEW* ViewControllerA.  If you want the existing ViewControllerA you need to pass it down the chain of controllers.  If that becomes problematic, you could make a property on the app delegate to store it.  Philosophically some people may object to using the app delegate as a global variable clearinghouse, but it might be cleaner than passing the pointer down through 4 levels of view controller.  Are you sure you need the delegate pattern in this case?  Maybe NSNotificationCenter would be a cleaner option?

Comment: Make sense. But could you give me an example of accessing the viewController?

Comment: You access it like any other instance variable or property.  Since you have "B" in the way, you can create a property on B to hold the reference to A, and then pass that on to C.  So you'd do that in the prepareForSegue from A to B.  Then when B creates C, stick the reference to A into C.  It's kind of janky when B doesn't really need the reference to A, other than to pass it on. That's why I think another design might be cleaner. Without knowing what you need C to communicate to A, it's hard to say though.  Maybe you really need a separate data model that both A & C observe?